# Task WaitAll not working properlyin C# for DB task

Tags: c#, linq, async-await

I'm playing around async LINQ a little bit upon Northwind DB but run into an issue with `Task.WaitAll(task1, task2)`. Below is method I'm calling from `static void Main(string[] args)`.

```
public static void PerformDatabaseOperations()
{
    using (var ne = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var aup = ne.Products.AverageAsync(p => p.UnitPrice)
               .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Average unit price is {t.Result}"));

            var ao = ne.Orders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate).AverageAsync(group => (double)group.Count())
                .ContinueWith(t => Console.WriteLine($"Average orders per day is {t.Result}"));

            Task.WaitAll(aup, ao);
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }       
    }
}
```

This throws AggregateException when I run it:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> 
System.NotSupportedException: A second operation started on this context before a previous asynchronous operation completed. Use 'await' to ensure that any asynchronous operations have completed before calling another method on this context. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
```

Is there anything I'm missing in this approach? I appreciate any of your hint.

Comment: `Task.WaitAll` doesn't grantee order of the execution. Is it important in your case? Seems it is... Seems `ao` should be continuation of `aup`

Comment: The error has *nothing* to do with `Task.WaitAll`, other than the fact that *anything* waiting on those tasks will *reveal* the exceptions that have been set in the `Task`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DbContext is not thread safe - you cannot use the same instance in 2 threads.

Following advice from the exception, just change your code to:

```
public static async Task PerformDatabaseOperations()
{
    using (var ne = new NORTHWNDEntities())
    {
        try
        {
            var t = await ne.Products.AverageAsync(p => p.UnitPrice);
            Console.WriteLine($"Average unit price is {t}");

            var ao = await ne.Orders.GroupBy(o => o.OrderDate).AverageAsync(group => (double)group.Count());
            Console.WriteLine($"Average orders per day is {ao}");
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }       
    }
}
```

Notice `async Task` in method definition.

If you really want to perform two queries at the same time, each task needs its own DbContext instance.

Comment: t.Result throws another error now: 'decimal?' does not contain a definition for 'Result' and no accessible extension method 'Result' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal?' could be found

Comment: sorry, no need for `t.Result`, should just t :)